# What does the Church have to say about the Pope's latest statement?

Tags: catholicism, hell, adam-and-eve, pope-francis

It is alleged that Pope Francis recently said that [There Is No Hell Fire and Adam & Eve were Not Real](http://entertainment.vacancynigerians.com/2013/12/shocking-there-is-no-hell-fire-adam-eve.html). What does the Catholic Church have to say about it?

Comment: [Here is another article](http://www.pittnews.com/opinion/article_2e2f8312-8494-11e3-8226-001a4bcf6878.html) related to Pope

Comment: Who speaks for the RCC if it is not the pope?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The statements ascribed to Pope Francis by that article are not true. It is a hoax.

See:

- [Don’t fall for this Pope Francis hoax: 5 things to know and share](http://www.ncregister.com/blog/jimmy-akin/dont-fall-for-this-pope-francis-hoax-5-things-to-know-and-share)
- [Pope Francis Declares All Religions are True : Facts (Hoax or Fact)](http://www.hoaxorfact.com/Politics/pope-francis-declares-all-religions-are-true-facts.html)

Comment: Right I'm having trouble finding his transcripts. But he is just a leader right, it doesn't matter what he says or is said about him.

Comment: since it's a hoax, it is no longer need to be discussed, thus i edited the text, leaving the original question for future users, if they ever see the hoax too

Answer (score 4):

The article that was quoted does not accually exist. It was a false story that was brought forth from the diversity chronicle. They provided a disclaimer on the article found here: 
[disclaimer](http://diversitychronicle.wordpress.com/disclaimer/)

[Here is a site that talks about the fake story](http://www.snopes.com/politics/satire/francis.asp)

Comment: his personal amusement went viral on facebook

Answer (score -2):

While that article in particular is a hoax... Each point in particular has been made and is old news.

- Benedict XVI said that Genesis is based on a myth
- Benedict XVI said that Heaven and Hell are not actual places
- Benedict XVI abolished Limbo of the Children.
- Francis says that atheists can be saved.

Benedict XVI called Genesis a rehashing of pagan myths
The pagan creation accounts on which the biblical story is in part based end without exception in the establishment of a cult, but the cult in this case is situated in the cycle of the do ut des.”
“Cardinal” Joseph Ratzinger, A New Song for the Lord, 1995, p. 86:

Benedict XVI abolished the Limbo of the Children and rejects infant baptism
"This state people called limbo.  In the course of our century, that has gradually come to seem problematic to us.  This was one way in which people sought to justify the necessity of baptizing infants as early as possible, but the solution is itself questionable"
“Cardinal” Joseph Ratzinger, God and the World, 2000, p. 401:

Comment: In this case, I guess we should open a  new question and discuss those subjects

Comment: [What does the Church say about the statements that the Pope Benedict XVI made in the book "God and the World"?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/24437)

Comment: I thought limbo was eliminated for children at Vatican II. Am I confused?